# use the fact that $\tan 2x=\sin2x \ /\cos2x$ to prove that $\tan 2x=2\tan x/(1-\tan^2x)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I need to use the fact that  $\tan 2x=\sin2x \ /\cos2x$ to prove that:
$$\tan 2x=\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2x}$$
I don't know where to start. Please help or hint. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

Use the identities:
$$ \cos{(2x)}=\cos^2{(x)}-\sin^2{(x)}$$
and 
$$ \sin{(2x)}=2\sin(x)\cos(x) $$

since you'll get:
$$ \frac{2\sin(x)\cos(x)}{\cos^2{(x)}-\sin^2{(x)}} $$
can you take it from there?

Comment: Yes thank you very much for your quick and helpful reply

Comment: @igeer12 No worries, glad to help!