# Simplifying $\frac{6\tan x }{1-\tan^2 x}$ to $3 \tan 2x$

Tags: trigonometry

> How do I perform the following simplification?
>   $$\frac{6\tan x }{1-\tan^2 x} \qquad\to\qquad 3 \tan 2x$$

I tried to take a common factor from denominator then use the laws of trigonometry, but I got nothing. Please explain the steps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply note that the following identity holds

$$\tan 2x =\frac{2\tan x}{1-\tan^2 x}$$

which can be easily checked by the following

- $\tan{2x}=\frac{\sin {2x}}{\cos{2x}}$
- $\sin{2x}=2\sin x\cos x$
- $\cos{2x}=\cos^2{x}-\sin^2{x}$

Comment: tan2x it this law?

Comment: it is a standard identity, look here for the proof https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/787255/use-the-fact-that-tan-2x-sin2x-cos2x-to-prove-that-tan-2x-2-tan-x-1?rq=1

Comment: i really thank you  :)

Comment: You are welcome, you should become aware about this basic trigonometric identities, take a look here for a complete summary and try to derive all of them by the definitions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Angle_sum_and_difference_identities